# Open workbook, read worksheet names, separate into blocks

Tags: vba, excel

I need a macro that will

1. Open a workbook,
2. Read the worksheet names into a drop down menu (so they are selectable),
3. Input a block size, and the number of blocks then
4. Split accordingly.

Scenario:  I have a workbook of data (3 worksheets) that 3 people will perform work on.  I want each of them to get a block of 100 rows from the worksheet that I select.  The macro should then cut the three blocks of 100 from the worksheet and paste them into 3 new workbooks to be distributed.

**From the comments:**

I have a button that runs the following code to select and open a workbook:

```
Sub Macro1() 
Dim fNameAndPath As Variant, wb As Workbook 
fNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel files (*.XLS), *.XLS", _
               Title:="Select the file to be opened") 
Workbooks.Open (fNameAndPath) 
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Reading [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) will help you get an answer sooner. Remember, this isn't a code-writing service, so post what you've got & we can help you fix it. If you don't know where to start, try using the Macro Recorder.

Comment: Sorry.  I'll read the link and try to follow.  I'm just getting started.  I have a button that runs the following code to select and open a workbook:  Sub Macro1()
    Dim fNameAndPath As Variant, wb As Workbook
    fNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel files (*.XLS), *.XLS", Title:="Select the file to be opened")
    Workbooks.Open (fNameAndPath)
End Sub

Comment: What I'd like to do next is read the worksheet names and put them into a drop down which i can then choose which worksheet to cut the blocks from.  it doesn' t have to be a dropdown if there is a cleaner way.  just need to read the names so one can be chosen

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a loop such as

```
For Each ws in ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    Name = ws.Name
    With Sheet1.ComboBox1
        .AddItem Name
    End With
Next
```

To reference each sheet individually and get the name of each sheet and add them to a comboBox. You can select an area of a worksheet with

```
ActiveSheet.Range(A1:A100)
```

If youre accepting the column letter as a number here is a function to convert that number into a letter

```
Function ConvertToLetter(ColumnNumber As Integer) As String
Dim n As Long
Dim c As Byte
Dim s As String

n = ColumnNumber
'Algorithm for converting number to column letter
Do
    c = ((n - 1) Mod 26)
    s = Chr(c + 65) & s
    n = (n - c) \ 26
Loop While n > 0
ConvertToLetter = s
End Function
```

Here is part of a function to create new workbooks from sheets. I use the condition, if the sheet is visible, but that's not necessary.

```
If sh.Visible = -1 Then

        sh.Copy

        'Set Destwb to the new workbook
        Set Destwb = ActiveWorkbook

        'Determine the Excel version and file extension/format
        With Destwb
            If Sourcewb.Name = .Name Then
                MsgBox "Your answer is NO in the security dialog"
                GoTo GoToNextSheet
            Else
                Select Case Sourcewb.FileFormat
                Case 51: FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
                Case 52:
                    If .HasVBProject Then
                        FileExtStr = ".xlsm": FileFormatNum = 52
                    Else
                        FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
                    End If
                Case 56: FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = 56
                Case Else: FileExtStr = ".xlsb": FileFormatNum = 50
                End Select
            End If
        End With

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False

        'Save the new workbook and close it
        With Destwb
            .SaveAs FolderName & "\" & workbookname & FileExtStr,     FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
        End With
    End If
```

I know this isnt a full solution, so I apologize for that. But I'm hoping you can piece it together from here.

Comment: Why is using the for each loop not sufficient for getting the worksheet names? I can see youre still asking for that in the comments of your question.